# Use a Query Function To Calculate A New Column Based On Data in Certain Rows of The Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to include a column in my query function that calculates the max value of each row in the query's columns 2-7.

The spreadsheet can be seen here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YCGU0toCxj1fhPXnrzPQO5aaiZVgkVE3tNzbQnLEzyM/edit?usp=sharingbasically I want the query function of cell M1 to calculate the Max Score column of column T that I created manually. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LAMBDA(quer,{quer,BYROW(quer,LAMBDA(each,IF(INDEX(each,,1)="Ign","Best round",MAX(each))))})(query($A1:$J187,"select A, sum(B) group by A pivot E",1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow Thank You! Where should I start if I want to learn how to do this? That was a quick response and seems pretty complex

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! You can read about [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) - it basically allows you to handle any formula naming the variables. I used in order not to repeat that query several times in the formula, just by naming it "quer". Another thing is [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) that allows you to do calculations row by row (that's how I handled to calculate MAX in each row). And last but not least how to make [arrays with curly brackets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: That last theme allowed me to insert that last column at the right of the query (in which I used the BYROW and etcetera)